# Elements from other states are only invisible, but still present in current view when using $stateProvider with Famo.us/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, famo.us

We've made a simple app that consists of two views configured with $stateProvider.

The issue we've encountered is a result of traversing from one view to the other, without refreshing the page. What happens is the elements from both views are present, but the elements from the view not currently active are set to an opacity of 0, meaning that they attract attention when EventHandlers are involved (in our case it's a ScrollView and a Click event that are sucked up by these invisible elements).

Is this common behaviour when switching between states/routes with $stateProvider, or is this specific to Famo.us/Angular? Shouldn't Angular detach these irrelevant elements from the DOM, since the current view is not the one where these said elements are contained? Are we missing something trivial?

Below is our $stateProvider configuration.

```
angular.module('famousAngularApp', ['ui.router', 'famous.angular'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('menu', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html',
            controller: 'MenuCtrl'
        })
        .state('reader', {
            url: '/reader',
            templateUrl: 'partials/reader.html',
            controller: 'ReaderCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

All of the surfaces contained in the views named above are image surfaces.